# I need a way to concatenate unknown last cell with other cell and use a format with leading zeroes

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried to use number.format = "00000000000000000" for the cell but it does not concatenate with the leading zeroes

```vb
Range("A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Formula = "=(" & Range("A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) & ")&(" & text(" & Range("B" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) & "),00000000000000000)"
```

I expected the cells to concatenate with that expected format but I have Comile error

Comment: You are combining VBA syntax with Worksheet syntax. Also could you show what you are trying to achieve through an example?

Comment: Can you enter the formula here as you would manually do in Excel?

Comment: I simply want to concatenate the last row in column A and the last row in column B. But I want last row in column B to be in the format (00000000000000000)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Formula in excel would have been          
  =A149& TEXT(B149,"00000000000000000") but A149 and B149 will not always be the last rows

Comment: You mean A and B can have different last rows? For example `=A149& TEXT(B150,"00000000000000000")` If yes then see the Edit. Take your pick...

Answer (score 3):

Best to work with `Objects` and `Variables`. Your code becomes clean and managable.

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lrow As Long
    Dim sFormula As String

    Set ws = Sheet1 '<~~ Change this to the relevant sheet

    With ws
        lrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        sFormula = "=A" & lrow & "&TEXT(B" & lrow & ",""00000000000000000"")"

        .Range("A" & lrow + 1).Formula = sFormula
    End With
End Sub
```

If Col A and Col B have different last rows then use this code

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lrowA As Long, lrowB As Long
    Dim sFormula As String

    Set ws = Sheet1

    With ws
        lrowA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row '<~~ Col A Last Row
        lrowB = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row '<~~ Col B Last Row

        sFormula = "=A" & lrowA & "&TEXT(B" & lrowB & ",""00000000000000000"")"

        .Range("A" & lrowA + 1).Formula = sFormula
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted. It works perfectly. Thanks

Comment: Like I said "work with Objects and Variables". It will be easy to understand what you are doing :)

Comment: the first one works fine. what if I also want to concatenate last row in column C too but in "0000" format.                     
        sFormula = "=A" & lrow & "&TEXT(B" & lrow & ",""00000000000000000"") & "&TEXT(C" & lrow & ",""000000"") & "&TEXT(D" & lrow & ",""00000"")" gives compile error.

Comment: @SojiCoker. Firt type the formula in Excel and then edit it in VBA ;)

Comment: @SojiCoker: If you notice that you ar emissing quotes after the bracket in 0's. Is this what you are trying? `sFormula = "=A" & lrow & "&TEXT(B" & lrow & ",""00000000000000000"")" & "&TEXT(C" & lrow & ",""000000"")" & "&TEXT(D" & lrow & ",""00000"")"`